# Running servlet I only get a Hello World

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, netbeans, glassfish

When I run my project, even if I make so many mistakes (like changing the name of the method doGet() to domGet)it keeps opening the browser with a "Hello World!". I don't know why it keeps doing this, I stopped Tomcat server and still I get the Hello World sign. I hope you can help me, I spent hours looking for a solution. Here is the code

```
package alumni;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ServletPersonaa extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public ServletPersonaa()   {
    super();
    }

    @Override
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        // Envia información
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Datos de la Persona </title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");

        out.println("El nombre es: " + request.getParameter("nombre"));
        out.println("<BR>");
        out.println("El apellido es: " + request.getParameter("apellido"));
        out.println("<BR>");
        out.println("El domicilio es: " + request.getParameter("domicilio"));
        out.println("<BR>");
        out.println("El pais es: " + request.getParameter("pais"));
        out.println("<BR>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        out.close();
   }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    }
```

Comment: have you changed the code which is deployed on your server to this code?

Comment: Must be another Servlet class.

Comment: Are you sure you are calling this servlet? Try to add this to the class beginning: 

`@WebServlet(name = "servletpersonaa", urlPatterns = { "/servletpersonaa" })
public class ServletPersonaa extends HttpServlet ` and call it in your form for example like this: `<form method="GET" action="servletpersonaa">`. With a form, you probably want to use a POST but that should work for now :) And if you want a better help, post also the .jsp-Page you are using.

Comment: The problem was I hadn't modified the HTML file -so silly of me. Thank you all for your help.